# Time-based rgb color transition

Tags: python, algorithm, rgb, led

I try to write a python waking light function based on a defined timespan. The function should handle a list of rgb values `[(0,0,0), (204,156,0), (255,255,255)]`. Zero means the led is off, 255 means the full intensity. The `duration_of_light` is a fixed number of seconds. That means that for n (number of rgb values to reach) I'll have (n-1) equaly timespans (`timespan = duration_of_light/n-1`).

For example:

`timespan = 30/3-1 = 15` (15 seconds between the transition of `(0,0,0)` and `(204,156,0)` and 15 seconds between the transition of `(204,156,0)` and `(255,255,255)`.

It was a very simple procedure to increase either the `r`, `g`, or `b` value by a fixed pixel offset (I've increased each second the corresponding rgb value with the offsets:

```
offset_red = 204-0/timespan=13.6 #(rounded -> +14 to the red value each second).
offset_green = 156-0/timespan=10.4 #(rounded -> +10 to the green value each second).
offset_blue = 0-0 #(not increased in the first timespan)
```

But this resulted in a waking light that has no smooth transition, because it steps up in a fixed number of red, green, or blue amount each second (as expected).

Is there any solution for a time-based smooth transition without implementing additional threads to update the `r`, `g` and `b` values separatly? I think at least two additional threads are needed.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't update the values at a faster rate? For example, it will look much smoother if you update them every 0.1 second.

Comment: Rgb is not really suited to do smooth transitions - if that is what you want to do. You could consider the hsv or hsl color models.